# jQuery chosen max_selected_options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am using chosen to populate my select elements. The only area I am having trouble with is that the `max_selected_options` is not being recognised. For exampl, i have set this option to 3 but nothing happen. Still allows me to select more items. There are no errors in firebug or inspector.

I have checked the site and can see no examples on how to do this. I have posted my code and shall be grateful if someone could point out my error. Many thanks.

js

```
$(function() {
  $("#box_rtn").chosen({
    width: "250px",
    max_selected_options: 3
  });
  $("#box_rtn").bind("chosen:maxselected", function() {
    $("#message").html('You cannot select more than 3 boxes');
  });
});
```

html

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="box_rtn" class="labelStyle">Select Your Box(es)</label>
  <select class="form-control chosen-select" name="box_rtn[]" id="box_rtn" multiple data-placeholder="No boxes to display...">
    <option value=""></option>
  </select>
  <div id="rtrnmessage"></div>
  <div class="servicesHelp"><lead id="serviceHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Please select your boxes from the list. You can select a max of 3 boxes per submission. You can select multiple boxes by holding the left ctrl on your keyboard and making your selection</lead>
  </div>
  <div id="message" style="color:white;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
var config = {
           '.chosen-select'           : {max_selected_options: 3},
           '.chosen-select-deselect'  : {allow_single_deselect:true},
           '.chosen-select-no-single' : {disable_search_threshold:10},
           '.chosen-select-no-results': {no_results_text:'Oops, nothing found!'},
           '.chosen-select-width'     : {width:"95%"}
         }
         for (var selector in config) {
           $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
         }
```

When you configuring your jquery chosen.